# 403 Error during http request using angular (post)

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-403

I made a form with angularJS validation and my code is working fine in localhost. When I try to upload my whole code on my web server, I encounter a 403 Error ( Forbidden ) on line 72 of my angular.min.js file.

I tried A LOT of solutions and I am stuck on this problem.

Here is what I have in my javascript file, the problem seems to come from my server or there as I don't even get into my `insert.new.php` file due to this 403 error.

```
function FrmController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.errors = [];
    $scope.msgs = [];
    $scope.titles = [];

    $scope.SignUp = function() {

        $scope.errors.splice(0, $scope.errors.length); // remove all error messages
        $scope.msgs.splice(0, $scope.msgs.length);
        $scope.titles.splice(0, $scope.titles.length);

        $http.post('insert.new.php', { 'uname': $scope.username, 'email': $scope.useremail }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data.msg != '') {
                $scope.titles.push(data.title);
                $scope.msgs.push(data.msg);
                sendContactForm();
            } else {
                $scope.titles.push(data.title);
                $scope.errors.push(data.error);
                sendContactForm();
            }
        }).error(function(data, status) { // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            $scope.titles.push(data.title);
            $scope.errors.push(status);
            sendContactForm();
        });
    }

}
```

I tried to put a .htaccess at the root of my website, the file contains

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
```

I didn't change anything on my webserver itself, it has a "firewall" that i tried to disable in case it could help, but that didn't solve anything.

Using AngularJS 1.2.3 (this version is the highest version that works with this code)

When I submit, in the "source" tab of chrome I get :

```
angular.min.js:72 POST http://domain.com/insert.new.php 403 (Forbidden)
angular.min.js:72 XHR finished loading: POST 
"http://domain.com/insert.new.php".
```

I think there is a big chance that it has something to do with apache / the configuration of my server, but I cant solve it and nothing that I found until now did help me.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem on puting an .htaccess in all of my documents, one at the root wasn't enough, so problem solved !